# How to fix character encoding issue in GitHub Actions when using Verify in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, github-actions, xunit, verify

I'm using [Verify](https://github.com/VerifyTests/Verify) lib to assert my xUnit test results in a C# project. Locally, everything works fine, but when I push my changes to GitHub, the tests in GitHub Actions fail.

The problem is that I have some Spanish special characters that are not being compared properly when the files are compared using Verify in GitHub Actions. I suspect that this is because the encoding is not set correctly in the GitHub Actions environment.

Here's a fragment of code that reproduces the issue:

```
var clientResponse = new
{
    Error = new
    {
        Email = new string[]
        {
            "Email inválido"
        }
    }
};

await Verify(new
{
    response.StatusCode,
    clientResponse
});
```

The error message from GitHub Actions is as follows:

```
expected:
{
  "StatusCode": 422,
  "clientResponse": {
    "Error": {
      "Email": [
        "Email inválido"
      ]
    }
  }
}
but was:
{
  "StatusCode": 422,
  "clientResponse": {
    "Error": {
      "Email": [
        "Email inv?lido"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the special character "í" is being incorrectly displayed as "?". How can I fix this character encoding issue with Spanish special characters when using Verify in GitHub Actions for xUnit tests?

[image: Error message]

I tried adding the /p:ConsoleEncoding=UTF8 parameter to my YAML file to set the console encoding to UTF-8.

```
name: .NET

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 7.0.x
    - name: Add GitHub Source
      shell: bash
      run: dotnet nuget add source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/.../index.json --name github --username ${{ secrets.NUGET_USERNAME }} --password ${{ secrets.NUGET_AUTH_TOKEN }} --store-password-in-clear-text
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --no-restore
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-build --verbosity normal /p:ConsoleEncoding=UTF8
```

Unfortunately, setting the console encoding to UTF-8 did not fix the issue. The same error occurred, with special characters being displayed incorrectly in the received.txt.

Comment: Is your C# source file definitely *in* UTF-8? Note that you could always use an escape sequence, e.g. `"Email inv\u00E1lido"` - that might be worth *trying* as a starting point, so you know whether the problem is with the C# compilation or elsewhere.

Comment: You are using `ubuntu-latest` runner. Is that intentional? Are you using Ubuntu as your local machine where it's working fine?

Comment: based on the naming of your tests, you're comparing files, how are those files written and read?

Comment: @Azeem You're right. I was using Windows locally. I changed the "runs-on" parameter to "windows-latest" and the tests worked fine. However, the test execution time increased to more than 5 minutes compared to ubuntu-latest which only took 3 minutes.

Comment: @RicardoYanez: Good to hear that. Check the actual run time of the steps, not including the total time which may include the wait time too depending on the availability of the runner.

Comment: Please let me know if you find the solution to this issue